# Form params not getting passed

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

What are some reasons form params would not show up in the console after form submit?  I have a form with nested attributes, that has been working fine.  Suddenly, the nested params stopped saving to the database.  Running debugger in the create action reveals that the nested params are not being sent with the form.

Strong params are set correctly, and were working before.
Im using .new in the controller action to build an instance of the nested objects

I did end up building the id and name attributes of the inputs manually due to some functionality I was looking for...but, again...this was already working.

Im using rails 4.0.2.

Are there any other aspects I could be missing as to why my nested fields are not showing up in the debugger params?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this error was from a misplaced html closing tag.  Sometimes the form elements got passed and other times they didn't.  It was a hard one to track down, because I was looking at active record and rails...when I should have looked at html as well.  I finally found it because I was debugging the code in the browser and noticed that the form elements were outside of the form tag.